# animate package plotting problem

Tags: pstricks, animations, pst-3dplot

I want to use the example in the example of an­i­mate package. But I cannot run it successfully. I found no pst-ode package in the package manager. But I installed it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\usepackage{pst-ode}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
%Lorenz’ set of differential equations
\def\lorenz{%
10*(x[1]-x[0]) | %dx/dt
x[0]*(28-x[2]) - x[1] | %dy/dt
x[0]*x[1] - 8/3*x[2] %dz/dt
}%
%
%write timeline file
\newwrite\OutFile%
\immediate\openout\OutFile=lorenz.tln%
\multido{\iLorenz=0+1}{101}{%
\immediate\write\OutFile{::\iLorenz x0}%
}%
\immediate\write\OutFile{::c,101}%
\multido{\iLorenz=102+1}{89}{%
\immediate\write\OutFile{::\iLorenz}%
}%
\immediate\closeout\OutFile%
%
\psset{unit=0.155,linewidth=0.5pt}%
\begin{animateinline}[
timeline=lorenz.tln,
controls,poster=last,
begin={\begin{pspicture}(-39,-13)(39,60)},
end={\end{pspicture}}
]{10}
%coordinate axes
\psset{Alpha=120,Beta=20}%
\pstThreeDCoor[xMax=33,yMax=33,zMax=55,linecolor=black]%
\newframe
\pstODEsetOrRestoreState{10 10 30} %initial condition
\multiframe{100}{i=0+1,rtZero=0+0.25,rtOne=0.25+0.25}{%
\pstODEsaveState{savedState}%
%compute attractor segments, stored in ‘lorenzXYZseg’
\pstODEsolve[algebraic]{lorenzXYZseg}{0 1 2}{\rtZero}{\rtOne}{26}{savedState}%
{\lorenz}%
%compute the whole attractor, stored in ‘lorenzXYZall’, with the same stepping
\ifnum\i=0\relax%
\pstODEsolve[algebraic]{lorenzXYZall}{0 1 2}{\rtZero}{\rtOne}{26}{savedState}%
{\lorenz}%
\else%
\pstODEsolve[algebraic,append]{lorenzXYZall}{0 1 2}{\rtZero}{\rtOne}{26}%
{savedState}{\lorenz}%
\fi%
\listplotThreeD[plotstyle=line]{lorenzXYZseg}%
}%
\newframe% required between two \multiframe
\multiframe{90}{rAlpha=116+-4}{% fly-around
\psset{Alpha=\rAlpha,Beta=20}%
\pstThreeDCoor[xMax=33,yMax=33,zMax=55,linecolor=black]%
\listplotThreeD[plotstyle=line]{lorenzXYZall}%
}%
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

The code is also attached in the animate package.pdf,the figure looks like
[image: lorenz]
<sub>(source: [texwelt.de](http://texwelt.de/wissen/upfiles/11111111aa_ffshdsh_3_1.png))</sub>

If you are skillful with this package, please give me some help!Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are using a Debisan distribution which is often out-of-date.
Download
http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-ode

unpack and save the files in `~/texmf/tex/generic/pst-ode/`, then run `texhash` (not needed for TEXMFHOME but doesn't hurt) and the file should be found by

```
kpsewhich pst-ode.tex
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The pst-ode.sty can be found now. But the code stunk at \newframe. Can you run this code in your Tex and generate the PDF?

Comment: Also, 'undefined control sequence' shows.

Comment: I have no problem with `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` and then viewing it with acroread

Comment: Still can't run it out. Now the problem is TEX capacity exceeded. Main memory size=3000000

Comment: So sorry, but now comes with couldn't find header file: pst-ode.pro. I have run texhash before.

Comment: did you saved the `pst-ode.pro` in `~/texmf/dvips/pst-ode/`?